# when i run the code it throws invalid parameter exception how do i fix it?

Tags: wpf

so i decided to go on  a different direction,which was saving the picture name on the database and copying the image in a folder inside my application.

```
            while (reader.Read())
            { 
                    BitmapImage bitImg = new BitmapImage();
                    string fileName = 
                    System.IO.Path.GetFileName(reader.GetString(12));
                    System.Windows.Controls.Image img = new  
                    System.Windows.Controls.Image();

                    var impath="pack://application:,,,/TravelBuddyApp;component/images/" + fileName;
                    bitImg.UriSource = new Uri(impath, 
                    UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
                    img.Width = 100;
                    img.Height = 100;
                    img.Source = bitImg;
                    StackPanel sp = new StackPanel();
                    sp.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical;
                    sp.Children.Add(img);

                    listviewer.Items.Add(sp);
```

Answer (score 0):

`System.Drawing.Image` is WinForms. Do not use it a WPF application.

Use classes derived from `System.Window.Media.ImageSource`, e.g. `BitmapImage`:

```
var bmp = new BitmapImage();

using (var memStm = new MemoryStream(imageBytes))
{
    bmp.BeginInit();
    bmp.StreamSource = memStm;
    bmp.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    bmp.EndInit();
}

listviewer.Items.Add(bmp);
```

In case `listviewer` is a ListBox or ListView, there should be an Image element in the ItemTemplate:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listviewer">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: i tried your code but it threw an exception..System.NotSupportedException: 'No imaging component suitable to complete this operation was found.'

Comment: Then `imageBytes` does not contain a valid encoded image frame, e.g. a PNG or JPEG. What is it supposed to contain?

Comment: binary data from the database

Comment: <ListView x:Name="listviewer" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="800">
                 <ListView.View>
                   
                        
                 
                    <GridView x:Name="grid">
                        <GridViewColumn/>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>

Comment: Sure, but what kind of binary data? As said, it has to be an encoded image frame that can be decoded by one of the BitmapDecoders in WPF: PNG, JPEG, BMP, GIF or TIFF.

Comment: FileDialog fldlg = new OpenFileDialog();
                fldlg.InitialDirectory = Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures.ToString();
                fldlg.Filter = "Image File (*.jpg;*.bmp;*.gif)|*.jpg;*.bmp;*.gif";
                fldlg.ShowDialog();

Comment: if (imageName != "")
                {
                    //Initialize a file stream to read the image file
                    FileStream fs = new FileStream(imageName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

                    //Initialize a byte array with size of stream
                    byte[] imgByteArr = new byte[fs.Length];

                    //Read data from the file stream and put into the byte array
                    fs.Read(imgByteArr, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));

                    //Close a file stream
                    fs.Close();

Comment: this i used to insert to the database

Comment: Please, do not post all that code in comments. If there is anything relevant, edit your question.

Comment: That said, reading a byte array from a file is done in a single line: `byte[] buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);`

Comment: Sorry, what? You are already adding objects to the Items collection of the ListView.

Comment: it is still throwing an exception ,System.NotSupportedException: 'No imaging component suitable to complete this operation was found.'

Comment: Because the byte array you get back from the database is not a valid image frame. No idea why, perhaps it is not the same as the one you've read from the image file.

Comment: the folder i read the image file and the code  i posted  are not on the same wpf window

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to say. If you read all the bytes from an image file (with a supported format like PNG), then store this byte array in a database and later retrieve it, the stored and retrieved byte array should be identical. You would then be able to create a BitmapImage as shown above.